# How do I keep my deserializeUser function in passport from running constantly after login?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs, express, authentication

I am having some trouble with my user authentication. I am able to log in, sign up, and log out just fine, and you might think from the client side that everything is great. However, my deserializeUser function is getting called repeatedly. Dozens of times per second. I didn't notice it initially, but if you are logged in long enough, the app really slows down. I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I've tried running client.end() at the end of the user.js file, but that did not solve the problem. I'm wondering if it's somehow a cross-origin issue.

-UPDATE - I don't suspect it's a CORS issue, as I just tried logging in from a static html file on the server port, and the problem remained.

*React on the front end running on a different port than the server. Node, Express, and Postgres on the server-side.

app.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    session = require('express-session');

require('dotenv').config();

let port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
});

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cookieParser('brothersofgroove'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'brothersofgroove',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,

    path:"/*" //NEEDED
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./passportconfig').configure(passport);

app.use('/', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/general'));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Your server is running on PORT ${ port }.`);
})
```

passportconfig.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const { Client } = require('pg');

const User = require('./models/user');

function configure(passport) {
  const strategyFunc = function(username, password, done) {
    User.checkUser(username, password, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Local Strategy - Error trying to authenticate.');
        done(err);
      } else if (user) {
        console.log('Local Strategy - Success');
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        console.log('Local Strategy - Could not find user');
        done(null, false);
      };
    });
  };

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(strategyFunc));
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser', user);
    done(null, user);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('deserializeUser', user);
    const userId = user.id;
    const client = new Client();

    client.connect().then(() => {
      const sql = 'SELECT * FROM backbeatuser WHERE id = $1';
      const params = [userId];

      return client.query(sql, params);
    }).then((results) => {
      const user = results.rows[0];
      done(null, user);
    }).catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    }).then(() => {
      client.end();
    });
  });
};

module.exports = { configure };
```

auth.js

```
const express = require('express'),
      bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'),
      { Client } = require('pg'),
      passport = require('passport'),
      router = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/backbeat',
  failureRedirect: '/notloggedin',
  failureFlash: true
}));

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {

  const firstName = req.body.firstName,
        lastName = req.body.lastName,
        email = req.body.email,
        username = req.body.username,
        password = req.body.password,
        city = req.body.city,
        skillLevel = req.body.skillLevel;

  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  const passwordHash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
  const client = new Client();

  client.connect().then(() => {
    const sql = `
      INSERT INTO backbeatuser
        (first_name, last_name, email, username, password_hash, city, skill_level, onboarding_stage)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)
        RETURNING *
      `;

    let params = [firstName, lastName, email, username, passwordHash, city, skillLevel, 0];

    params = params.map((param) => {
      if (param === '') {
        param = null;
      };
      return param;
    });

    return client.query(sql, params);
  }).then((results) => {
    const user = results.rows[0];
  }).then(() => {
    next();
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.redirect('/');
  }).then(() => {
    client.end();
  });

}, passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/backbeat'
}));

router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  // res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

user.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'),
      { Client } = require('pg');

const checkPassword = function(password, passwordHash) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, passwordHash);
}

const checkUser = function(username, password, done) {
  const client = new Client();

  client.connect().then(() => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM backbeatuser WHERE username = $1';
    const params = [username];

    return client.query(sql, params);
  }).then((results) => {
    console.log('username results', results.rows);
    const user = results.rows[0];

    if (user && checkPassword(password, user.password_hash)) {
      console.log('Should be a successful login');
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      console.log('The user probably entered the incorrect password');
      done(null, false);
    };
  });
};

module.exports = { checkUser };
```